# is there any rest API in bitbucket which can download the file at particular commit?

Tags: api, file, download, bitbucket

I know about this API

/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path:.*}?at={commitId}

But with this API for binary files we get this response

```
{
    "binary": true,
    "path": {
        "components": [
            "src",
            "log-output.7z"
        ],
        "parent": "src",
        "name": "log-output.7z",
        "extension": "7z",
        "toString": "src/log-output.7z"
    }
}
```

For text files we get this response

```
{
    "lines": [
        {
            "text": "abcd"
        }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "isLastPage": true
}
```

I can re-create files with API response for text but is there any way to download the binary file or to get their size ?